# ADFS 2.0 with forms authentication type doesn't redirect to the url on wreplay parameter after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, wif, adfs2.0, ws-federation

I am using ADFS with forms authentication type, after sign-out i cannot redirect to a URL in the wreply parameter. I always get the forms log-in page. Why does it happen?

If I change the ADFS web.config to Integrated authentication type, after log-out I'm being redirected to the URL in wreply, but when I click "Back" button, I'm logged in  without prompt for credentials by the IE browser.

Using fiddler I can see the empty sign-out cookie, which looks like this:

MSISSignOut=; expires=Tue, 01-Jun-2010 21:01:32 GMT; path=/adfs/ls

this is my code:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

//clear local cookie
authModule.SignOut(false);

//initiate federated sign out request to the STS
SignOutRequestMessage signOutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(authModule.Issuer), authModule.Realm + "/logout");
String queryString = signOutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString();
return new RedirectResult(queryString);
```

Comment: Do you have the default login url In your Web config? If so, try removing  that

Comment: I don't have login url on my web.config.

Comment: I can see with the debugger that after the i click logout, I get "WSFederationAuthentication_RedirectingToIdentityProvider" event, when I am using Integrated authentication type I get the logout function (which present the logout view) after that event but on forms authentication type I get the forms log-in page.